# Lua 5.0 - Why is my DLL not loading?

Tags: dll, lua

I am trying to load a DLL `power.dll` following [this tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm). However, I am getting the warnings

```
WARNING: ...it\faforever\fa\lua\ai\aiarchetype-managerloader.lua(48): could not load package `power' from path `E:\lua\'
WARNING: stack traceback:
WARNING:         [C]: in function `require'
```

Unfortunately there is not more output than that. All I know is that the game I try to modify "*uses uses a slightly modified version of Lua 5.0.*" [1] - whatever "*slightly*" is supposed to mean ..

The thing is that I tested this import with a Lua 5.3 standalone and it works. I can call that `square()` function (see [tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm)) but it's not working with the game.

Of course there is a chance the they simply do not allow loading a .dll simple as that but of course I hope than it's simply just me not seeing something or missing something out.

Is there a chance that somebody could help me with this (quite specific) question?

Am I doing it right, speaking in LUA 5.0 standards:

The file which is supposed to load my DLL simply calls:

```
_G.LUA_PATH = "E:\\lua\\"
require("power")
```

At first I got an error becacuse `LUA_PATH` was not defined as I called `require`. After defining `LUA_PATH` the `require` seems to work but something else still seems to fail here ..

[1] http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Lua

Comment: The official `require` function in Lua 5.1+ uses semicolon-separated path templates (e.g. `"E:\\lua\\?.dll;.\\?.dll"`) instead of directory names. You could try that ...

Comment: @siffiejoe Actually I am using Lua 5.0 - atm I am not sure if that can even load DLLs ..

Comment: I just thought that whoever implemented the `require` function for your slightly modified Lua 5.0 probably mimicked the standard version for Lua 5.1. The name `LUA_PATH` also suggests that. Bad news is that you'd need `LUA_CPATH` for DLLs, and since it didn't complain you are probably right in that loading DLLs is most likely not supported.

Comment: @siffiejoe Hm, I am going to try that but I am afraid it won't work :/